# Can I only expose a specific package in my gradle module?

Tags: java, gradle, module, architecture

In maven I have the opportunity to make submodules of submodules and so on. This way I can wrap a functionality in a module, give it a api- and a impl- submodule and let other modules only reference to the api submodule. Why can I not do this in Gradle? Is there any way to expose only on package (which contains my interfaces) to the referencing modules in replacment of a api submodule?

Or do I just use Gradle wrong?

Sorry if that's a stupid question.